# ¿Si signas un APK si luego haces un build ya se queda grabado?

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo una duda, una vez que he pulsado en Generate Sign APK y me creo el APK, cuando quiero después ir añadiendo código a la aplicación y quiero volver a generar el APK he de pulsar en Generate Sign APK otra vez para que me vuelva asignar la key o ya se me quedo grabado y solamente pulso build apk??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La opción:

> **Generate Signed APK...**

es para firmar el .apk mediante una Keystore, generalmente es la llave con la que firmarías tus aplicaciones para la Playstore.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas volver a firmar tu .APK debes usar nuevamente la opción **Generate Signed APK...**, ya que al construir nuevamente tu .APK este es firmado con un Keystore de DEBUG (**no se mantiene la firma anterior**!).

---

Si únicamente usas la opción

> **Build APK...**

tu aplicación será firmada únicamente con el Keystore de Debug y no serviría para ser una aplicación destinada para la playstore.

Answer (score 1):

La primera vez que creas un APK te pedira registro, pero luego utilizara ese mismo registro para las demas APK asi que no es necesario volver a registrar otra key, solo dale a generar apk y se te creara desntro de la carpeta del proyecto de android/app/build/outputs/apk

Answer (score 1):

Debes Generar la APK firmada cada vez que vayas a crear una nueva versión para publicar. SI pulsaste Generate Signed APK y antes de publicarla te diste cuenta que faltaba agregar un cambio, deberás hacer este proceso nuevamente para generar la APK con esos últimos cambios. Si ya publicaste una versión de tu APK en el Play Store y realizas cambios en el código, deberás cambiar en el archivo build.gradle(module app) el versionName de esta nueva APK que vas a crear al igual que el versionCode ya que no pueden coincidir en el Play Store estos valores de la APK que está publicada y el nuevo APK que vas a publicar.